# ASP.NET GridView Edit, Update, Delete commands broken with Chrome version 83

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms application that is using GridView with Edit, Update and Delete commands.  Each command worked correctly in Chrome version 81.  Since upgrading to Chrome version 83, the events are not firing.  In Visual Studio, I can see the Select Row event firing, but not the subsequent event.  I have tried a number of corrections including..

1. Upgrading all NuGet packages.
2. Upgrading from .NET Framework 4.7.2 to 4.8.
3. Forcing EnableViewState = true.
4. I've also tested with Edge, Firefox and Internet Explorer.  Edge version 83 does not work, but the prior version works.  Firefox current version does not work, but previous versions were not tested.  Internet Explorer works, but the CSS for the reminder of the site doesn't.

The following is the GridView code.  It is not contained within an update panel.

```
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" SelectedRowStyle-CssClass="selected" SelectedIndex="-1"  DataKeyNames="Id"
            AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" runat="server" CssClass="fixedHeader defaultRowSelector"
            OnRowEditing="GridViewEvent_OnRowEditing"
            OnRowUpdating="GridViewEvent_OnRowUpdating"
            OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewEvent_OnPageIndexChanging"
            OnRowCancelingEdit="GridViewEvent_OnRowCancelingEdit"
            OnRowDeleting="GridViewEvent_OnRowDeleting"
            OnSorting="GridViewEvent_OnSorting" 
            OnRowCommand="GridViewEvent_OnRowCommand" OnSelectedIndexChanging="GridViewEvent_OnSelectedIndex"
            >

            <PagerSettings Mode="Numeric" Position="Bottom" PageButtonCount="5" />

            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="editColumn">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnEdit" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" CausesValidation="false" />
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Update" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" CausesValidation="false" />
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" CausesValidation="false"/>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Delete" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?")' CausesValidation="false" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Id" DataField="Id" SortExpression="Id" ReadOnly="true" />               

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="Active">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ActiveDropDown" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Active") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="ActiveLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Active") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Username" DataField="Username" SortExpression="Username" ReadOnly="true" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="First Name" DataField="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Name" DataField="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Email" DataField="EmailAddress" SortExpression="EmailAddress" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role" SortExpression="UserRole">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="UserRoleDropDown" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("UserRoleId") %>' DataTextField="UserRole" DataValueField="UserRoleId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceUserRole" /> 
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="UserRoleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserRole") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vendor Name" SortExpression="VendorName" >
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="VendorDropDown" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("VendorId") %>' DataTextField="VendorName" DataValueField="VendorId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceVendor" AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
                            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="None" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="VendorNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VendorName") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: .. so you're saying your code only works in Internet Explorer? Do you see console errors in other browsers?

Comment: @stuartd The GridView Edit functionality, specifically, only works in Internet Explorer.  The same functionality was working correctly in Chrome and Edge until their latest versions were released on 5/19 and 5/21 respectively.

Comment: @stuartd The console in the browser does not display any error.  I've added logging to the server side and can see that only the Select event is triggered when clicking edit in Chrome and Edge.  In Internet Explorer, both the Select and Edit events are fired.